# Ошибка установки Python 3.9.0 на Windows 7 (Setup failed)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и как его исправить?
Пытался установить Python 3.9.0 на Windows 7 (Максимальная), но перед установкой (при запуске установщика) мне выдаёт такую ошибку:
[image: Скриншот]

Вот лог:

```
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Windows\Temp\{E3759934-CA2D-42C9-AFAB-D4D618024946}\.cr\python-3.9.0-amd64.exe
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'ShortVersion' to value '3.9'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '39'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVer' to value '3.9'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'WinVerNoDot' to value '39'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDir' to value ''
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value '[ProgramFiles64Folder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetPlatform' to value 'x64'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstallPath'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_core' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_exe' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_dev' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_lib' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_test' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_doc' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tools' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tcltk' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_pip' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_launcher' to value '-1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_symbols' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_debug' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LauncherOnly' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'AssociateFiles' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Shortcuts' to value '1'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrependPath' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CompileAll' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SimpleInstall' to value '0'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\User\Desktop\python-3.9.0-amd64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=180 -burn.filehandle.self=188'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\python-3.9.0-amd64.exe'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Python 3.9.0 (64-bit)_20201107140251.log'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.9.0 (64-bit)'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'
[14F4:1554][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting numeric variable 'CRTInstalled' to value 1
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Did not find C:\Users\User\Desktop\unattend.xml
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.9.150.0'
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]e000: Detected Windows 7
[14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]e000: Windows 8.1 or later is required to continue installation
```

Comment: В ошибке ведь говорится, что для установки `Python` требуется **Windows 8.1 или новее**. Для установки вам нужно обновить версию **Windows**.

Answer (score 3):

В логах четко написано, что у тебя вин7, а надо 8 и выше.

> ```
> [14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]e000: Detected Windows 7
> [14F4:05E8][2020-11-07T14:02:51]e000: Windows 8.1 or later is required to continue installation
> ```

Answer (score 0):

последняя версия, которая реально запускается на 7-ке, - это 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужна именно 3.9.0 и не раньше то... VMware/VirtualBox в студию. Я лично воспользовался версией 3.8.10 (норм поставилась на Win7) не смотря на то что про инструкции нужна более высшая. И могу сказать норм, свою работу делает